# Equivalence between path integral formalism and operator formalism on curved spacetimes and radial quantization for a 2D boson field

Tags: metric-tensor, curvature, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, qft-in-curved-spacetime

We know that the path integral formalism and operator formalism are equivalent on flat spacetime. I am wondering whether we can also make it explicit on a curved spacetime.

Let us consider a concrete problem where the action does not explicitly contain the metric, like a free boson field on a 2D plane:
\begin{eqnarray}
S=\int dzd\bar{z}\partial_z X(z,\bar{z})\partial_{\bar{z}}X(z,\bar{z})
\end{eqnarray}
with the traceless flat metric (Euclidean complex plane)
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{z\bar{z}}=1/2.
\end{eqnarray}
I am wondering how to prove that the path integral on the annulus {$1\leq|z|\leq r$}
\begin{eqnarray}
\int[dX]_g\exp(-S[X]|_{1\leq|z|\leq r})
\end{eqnarray}
with some appropriate boundary condition and $[dX]_g$ is defined under the diffeomorphism invariant way under $g_{z\bar{z}}$ which explicitly depends on the metric, is equivalent with the operator formalism
\begin{eqnarray}
r^{-L_0-\bar{L}_0},
\end{eqnarray}
where $L_0+\bar{L}_0$ is the Virasoro generator of dilation.

At the first glance, it appears quite obvious because $L_0+\bar{L}_0$ serves as the Hamiltonian in the radial direction. However, if we see the question conversely, why should we think the operator formalism $r^{-L_0-\bar{L}_0}$ is for the path integral under $g_{z\bar{z}}=1/2$ rather than other metrics like
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{z\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2z\bar{z}},
\end{eqnarray}
or even more general Weyl equivalent ones (since action does not contain this piece of information)?
How to see the role of metric explicitly when we want to go from the operator picture to the path-integral formula, and vice versa?

My guess is that when we start from the operator formula, we need the relations
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle X(z,\bar{z})|X'(z,\bar{z})\rangle=\delta[X(z,\bar{z})-X'(z,\bar{z})],
\end{eqnarray}
where the state represents the configuration and the delta-function is a functional type, and the canonical momentum
\begin{eqnarray}
\Pi_X(z,\bar{z})=-i\frac{\delta}{\delta X(z,\bar{z})}.
\end{eqnarray}
I guess that these relations need to be modified when we use $g_{z\bar{z}}\neq1/2$, but I have no systematic way to do it.